# How to remove displaytag runtime error

Tags: java, jsp, struts, displaytag

I am working with struts and using displaytag to show the data. But I generates runtime error and the root cause is 
"javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:"

Anyone who can help me to remove this error...?

Comment: You are missing some dependency, but for us to help you would need to post the complete exception message (with the class name after the "NoClassDefFoundError:" string...

Answer (score 0):

Which exactl class is not found?

Problably you need to add jstl and standard libraries to your classpath. Using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```